# Drupal Blocks Custom Display Naming Convention?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-blocks

http://www.rybm.org/login   <--- I'm trying to place a login block in the main content section on this page.

Under "Show Blocks on Specific Pages", I know I am supposed to list the page, and I've done this successfully, before... but I cannot get the block to display.

I have tried the following names:

login           /login       http://www.rybm.org/login     "login"

Am I missing something, or am I experiencing a website caching issue? Is there a naming convention that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page doesn't exist. I would recommend just using http://www.rybm.org/user as your login page.